# How to calculate length of an array in mongo collection?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have following structure in mongo collection

```
[{
"_id" : ObjectId("543fa67e9672ec37ebe3d028"),
"customerId" : "5429aed703646b52def71736",
"tagName" : "abc",
"tagMembers" : [
    "111",
    "112",
    "123"
]
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("543fa67e9672ec37ebe3d029"),
"customerId" : "5429aed703646b52def71736",
"tagName" : "pqr",
"tagMembers" : [
    "111",
    "112",
    "123"
]
}]
```

I want to calculate count of each tagMember.

How do I calculate it using mongo ??

Is it possible to get count without using aggregate??

Comment: What's wrong with using the aggregation framework?

Comment: @ kocko - Actually I am not able to get count of array 'tagMembers'

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregation framework and the [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator:

```
> db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "tagMembersLength" : { "$size" : "$tagMembers" } } }
])
{ "tagMembersLength" : 3 }
{ "tagMembersLength" : 3 }
```